# Android: NullPointerException when adding a button to a layout programmatically?

Tags: android, android-layout, nullpointerexception, android-view, android-button

I'm trying to write code that will pop up an input box and add a button to a LinearLayout with whatever the user entered as the button's text. Here's my code for the pop-up box

```
public void submitPublicQuestion(View view) {
    AlertDialog.Builder question = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    question.setTitle("Submit Question");
    question.setMessage("Enter question: ");

    // Set an EditText view to get user input 
    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    final View queue = this.findViewById(R.layout.activity_main_class);
    final Button newBtn = new Button(this);
    newBtn.setId((int) (Math.random() * 0xFFFFFFFF));
    question.setView(input);

    question.setPositiveButton("Submit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            String value = input.getText().toString();

            newBtn.setText(value);
            newBtn.setMinWidth(550);
            newBtn.setTextSize(24);
            newBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.CSQuestionsLayout);
            LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            newBtn.setLayoutParams(lp);

            ll.addView(newBtn);
            goToQueue(queue);
        }
    });

    question.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

        }
    });

    question.show();

}
```

This code results in a NullPointerException when I call `ll.addView(newBtn);`. What's the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

i guess it complaining ll is null.
in ur xml make sure there is linearlayout with id CSQuestionsLayout

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.CSQuestionsLayout);
```

Comment: I have an object with that ID in the XML. Does it matter that it's a different XML than the one this code is attached to? **EDIT:** It does. I'm an idiot. Do you know how to refer to a different XML file in the code?

Comment: maybe u can try put `final LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.CSQuestionsLayout);` outside the onclick before u set the positive button.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use LayoutInflator to refer to another xml y which is not used in setContentView like below

```
   LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);    
                     View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.y, null );
    ImageView img=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imgView);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add ,

```
        final Button newBtn = new Button(this);
        setContentView(newBtn);
```

for button without having id in xml